# sbt: Formal definition of ~ (tilde) operator

Tags: sbt

What is the formal definition of sbt tilde operator?
What runs upon which watchSource's change?

If I have a project A which depends on project B, and if I give a command ~blah in project A, does this mean that whenever I change B, blah runs on B? Or only compile runs on B? What about changing a shared project which both A and B depend on? 
What happens when A 'aggregates' B?